# @ng-bootstrap NgbDatepicker met "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ngb-datepicker'"

Tags: angular, bootstrap-datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I use **@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap** and **Angular2-cli**

with NgbDatepicker met errs :

NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule,NgbModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [TestComponent],
  exports: [TestComponent]
})
```

component--

> export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
>
> model: NgbDateStruct;
>
> }

and html--

> *< ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model">< /ngb-datepicker>*

when add TestModule to another module ,

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule,LoginRoutingModule,TestModule],
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
})
```

and html:

```
<app-test></app-test>
```

there is the err:

```
error_handler.js:47EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ngb-datepicker'.
1. If 'ngb-datepicker' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-datepicker' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("
  <ngb-datepicker #dp [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="model"></ngb-datepicker>

"): TestComponent@1:22ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:47next @ application_ref.js:272schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74onError @ ng_zone.js:119onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:64ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:113_loop_1 @ zone.js:379drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386
error_handler.js:52ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:52next @ application_ref.js:272schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74onError @ ng_zone.js:119onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:64ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:113_loop_1 @ zone.js:379drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386
error_handler.js:53Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ngb-datepicker'.
1. If 'ngb-datepicker' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-datepicker' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("
  <ngb-datepicker #dp [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="model"></ngb-datepicker>

"): TestComponent@1:22
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:429)
    at zone.js:406
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:203)
    at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone_impl.js:43)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:202)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:96)
    at zone.js:462
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:236)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.js:34)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:235)ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:53next @ application_ref.js:272schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74onError @ ng_zone.js:119onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:64ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:113_loop_1 @ zone.js:379drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386
zone.js:355Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ngb-datepicker'.
1. If 'ngb-datepicker' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-datepicker' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("
  <ngb-datepicker #dp [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="model"></ngb-datepicker>

"): TestComponent@1:22 ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ngb-datepicker'.
1. If 'ngb-datepicker' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-datepicker' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("
  <ngb-datepicker #dp [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="model"></ngb-datepicker>

"): TestComponent@1:22
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:18077:19)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:42938:51)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:42860:83
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at compile (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:42860:47)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:99970:28)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:71761:37)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:99969:34)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:99863:43)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:100229:57consoleError @ zone.js:355_loop_1 @ zone.js:382drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386
zone.js:357Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:(…)consoleError @ zone.js:357_loop_1 @ zone.js:382drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are missing FormsModule. Try importing like this-

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```

and use it in AppModule like this-

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, NgbModule ],
```

You can use ngbDatepicker  like this too-

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp1" [(ngModel)]="newItem.EndTime"  ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker" required>
```

sample plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZC3dOX9anbbNUMPEEd5W?p=preview

See if this helps.

Comment: `Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.`

Comment: Try importing FormsModule into your appModule

Comment: Yes this work for me also